# Are there any pre-made libraries or programs that generate well formed CPEs?

Tags: c++, ruby-on-rails, c, ruby

My company is currently pulling machine specific information (OS, architecture, etc...) from our client-side agents in order to track trends and information. We have this information mapped on the backend but now want to standardize this into [CPE](http://cpe.mitre.org/) (Common Platform Enumeration) format.

Does anyone know of any technologies that can generate well formed CPEs (either from the information we pass in or from the os directly)? Our agent is C/C++ and our backend is Ruby.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: That's a negative. I believe we just used a custom data struct to keep track of everything, but I honestly can't remember the details it's been so long.